# Error facing in binary search question using c++

Tags: c++, arrays, binary-search

I am trying to solve my university question these is my assignment question:

Question:

```
Given a sorted array arr containing n elements with possibly duplicate elements, the task is to find indexes of first and last occurrences of an element x in the given array.
Input:
n=9, x=5
arr[] = { 1, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 67, 123, 125 }
Output:  2 5
Explanation: First occurrence of 5 is at index 2 and last
             occurrence of 5 is at index 5.
```

I am facing Error in these line and I will find `first occurence` of element only :

```
 int n= sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
```

[image]

full code :

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int arr[] = { 1, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 67, 123, 125 };
    int n= sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    int x=5;
    int start=0;
    int end=n-1;
    int mid;

    while(start<end){
        mid=start+end/2;
        if(arr[mid]<x){
            start=mid-1;
            cout<<start;
            }
        else if(arr[mid]==x){
            end=mid-1;
            cout<<end;
            }
        else{
            end=mid-1;
            cout<<end;
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"I am facing Error in these line"* - **always** include the full error message causing grief, *verbatim*, when posting a question about an unexpected compilation error.

Comment: My code is running they give me no error and they will highlight these line `int n= sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])`

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that line (the questionable choice of type `int` notwithstanding). I suspect your *real* problem is your code has an infinite loop due to integer division truncation you weren't expecting. A *debugger* will make that much clearer, especially considering the simplicity of your test case. Consider what happens when `start` is `0`, and `end` is `3`.  Draw three columns (`start`, `end`, and `mid`) and walk your loop by hand if necessary.

Comment: Are you sure your code is running? To me it sounds like you are running a debugger and it is pausing on the first line.

Comment: yes it will pause on first line

Comment: @developer That's because that is how your debugger works. There's an option to turn that behaviour off, or you can just tell the program to continue running.

Comment: @developer Or you can just walk through the code like WhozCraig suggests.

Comment: Fyi, you're going to find `mid = start + end/2;` is isn't correct either. That should probably be `mid = start + (end-start)/2;`

Comment: I have share pic with you they will highlight these line when I run code

Comment: That's not an error; that's an active breakpoint that has paused your program on that line of execution. That's a *breakpoint* active in your debugger. Hit F5 and let it continue (at which point you'll see the plethora of other errors/problems already noted begin to manifest).

Comment: it will give me infinite `0`

Comment: any solution to  solve these problem?

Comment: @developer Yes use the debugger (that you already know a little bit about).

Comment: This might be off-topic but consider using `std::array<int,7> arr` instead. Then you can use `arr.size()`